# JUnit + Mockito how to test DAO layer

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito

I am using Spring, SpringMVC, Mybatis in the project.
First time to play with Mockito.

Before using Mockito, the test code looked like this

```
@Test
@Transactional
@Rollback
public void setNewUnifyPriceRoom() throws Exception {
    Map reqMap = new HashMap();
    reqMap.put("typeId", 21);
    reqMap.put("roomId", 19);

    roomDockingsMapper.setNewUnifyPriceRoom(reqMap);

    String isUnifyPriceRoom = roomDockingsMapper.isUnifyPriceRoom(19, 21);
    Assert.assertEquals("Y", isUnifyPriceRoom);
}
```

Then I found Mockito since I did not want to touch database during testing. I tried to write a BeforeClass as a data provider. However, I got stuck when I tried to return something after I did the ***setNewUnifyPriceRoom*** action

```
 private static RoomDockingsMapper mockRoomDockingsMapper;
    @BeforeClass
    public static void setup(){
        Map reqMap = new HashMap();
        reqMap.put("typeId", 21);
        reqMap.put("roomId", 19);
        mockRoomDockingsMapper = mock(RoomDockingsMapper.class);
        when(mockRoomDockingsMapper.setNewUnifyPriceRoom(reqMap)).thenReturn(??????);
    }
```

Basically what I want to do is after do ***setNewUnifyPriceRoom***, then in the thenReturn section to set ***isUnifyPriceRoom*** method return "Y".

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It is difficult to answer based on what you provided..can you add the code for your actual method which you are testing?

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to mock out the very method that you are testing. You want to mock out the database interaction that happens inside `setNewUnifyPriceRoom`, so that you can verify that the rest of the code is working correctly.